# VisualGDB c++ to RaPi Poco no such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, include, raspberry-pi2

I am taking over a project and am pretty new with this entire setup (linux/gdb/c++). This project did work at 1 point, on RaPi 1.

Using VisualGdb to compile a c++ program to run on a RaspberryPi 2. I've seen similar questions, but either the answers didn't work or I don't fully understand how to implement.

When I try to compile, I get a fatal error: library name: No such file or directory.

2 that I know of so far are:

## include "Poco/Data/Common.h"

## include "Poco/Data/SQLite/Connector.h"

I have a similar program that uses different poco libraries and it compiles fine. If I look in the External Dependencies of the project, I see Common.h and Connector.h. The GDB Makefile settings have pthread PocoFoundation PocoData PocoDatad PocoDataSQLite PocoDataSQLited libraries listed.

Tried a few things, but not really sure how to debug this. I don't seem to be able to find the files on the RaPi using find -iname "Common.h", but I can't find the ones that are working in the other project either using that method.

I've done the Complete Edition install of poco and run sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo rpi-update.

Tried to give as much info as I understand of this, but sure I missed something. Any help/suggestions would be great. Let me know if you need more info on something I didn't include.

Thanx ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue.
libmysqlclient-dev needs to be installed first for these libraries to get installed with the poco install.